# Has anyone hooked up BizTalk and Fogbugz?

Tags: biztalk, fogbugz

We have an intranet system that schedules routine tasks. We also have Fogbugz for bug tracking. When an urgent bug comes in, we track that task in the bugtracker. However, I need to write back to both the Intranet and our CMS. I'm thinking Biztalk as the middle piece, but am not sure the best way to go about it. Database adapter? Web services?

I know I can use the CMS adapter for Microsoft CMS. I'd love to hear your experiences with Fogbugz.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that watching the database for changes would be the best way to do it. That way, you could post any changes you saw happen in the FogBugz database through other Biztalk adapters.

Please keep us updated with what you decide to do - I'd be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Version 6 of the FogBugz API is pretty well documented at http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html. The API is implemented as an ASP page that accepts GET or POST params and returns XML after a user has been authenticated.

So, we can use the HTTP Send Adapter to POST requests to the FogBugz system, either updating bug records or retrieving information. The response from the API call is basic Xml that will be returned in the response body that can be read by BizTalk as necessary.

Be aware that the HTTP Send Adapter can only POST data - it cannot use the GET verb (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561642.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't FogBugz based on a SQL Server Database? Or do you use a hosted alternative?

If it's using a SQL Server you're controlling I'd just tie up two send ports to the process that read and handles the "FixBugMessage". One send port that uses the CMS Adapter and writes to the CMS and another that just uses the SQL Adapter and via an Stored Procedure writes to the FogBugz database.